# Two way Analytics API for iOS App

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics

Is there any Analytics service that provide an API for **two way service**. I want independent events to be recorded with the service at their server and then I want to fetch all events to the App to show my users that how much event activity is there in total.

Is there any such analytics service with API to post and fetch events?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics did have a Collection api and a Reporting API.

There is a SDK for the collection API: "Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

For the reporting API there is: "Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries

Comment: Currently Google Analytics doesn't works with armv7s architecture, but they promised some fix soon.

Comment: @Tatiana the latest SDK version 3.02 is working on a iPhone5 which is armv7s. do you mean arm64?